# C# Change type of object

Tags: c#, object, arraylist

My application makes a request to get all the users and stores the user object in an ArrayList.

```
 ArrayList userlist = new ArrayList();
 foreach (User user in response.users)
 {
    userlist.Add(user);
 }
```

So now i have an Arraylist of users.  I loop though the user list and populate a combo box.

```
        userList = Program.GetALLUsers();
        foreach (User user in userList)
        {
            cmbUserList.Items.Add(user.displayName);
        }
        cmbUserList.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

My next function get's the user details which takes User object as a Param so further calls can be made to get the details of the specific user object.

So now when I click on my getUserDetials button, it grabs the selected index from the combo box (should be the same index in the Arraylist) and passes it to the getUserDetails function.  For this example i just hardcoded index 1.

```
  User currentUser = userList[0];
```

It says it cannot convert type of object to user.

Anyideas how to get around it?

Comment: Why don't you use a `List<User>`? Times  have long gone by when you need an `ArrayList`.

Comment: You have to downcast. Everything in `ArrayList` is stored as `object` (one of many reasons its not used anymore)

Comment: `User currentUser = (User)userList[0]`, but yeah, if you're using .NET 2.0 or later, you should be using a [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) instead

Comment: Ahh.  I get what your saying about using a list.  Let me give that a shot.

Comment: `List<T>` is always better to use than `ArrayList` in my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User currentUser = (User)userList[0];
```

FYI you can also simply do ((User)userList[0]).ClassMember instead of using a variable. I'm not saying it's better, I'm showing a choice.

I do suggest you use List<> instead of ArrayList though.

```
List<User> userList = new List<User>();

foreach (User user in response.users)
{
    userlist.Add(user);
}
```

Then the objects are stored as a User already.

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution to that is to make an explicit cast:

```
User currentUser = (User)userList[0];
```

However, you would be better off using a `List<User>` instead of `ArrayList`. That way you don't have to cast the values.